# shading a brick problem

Tags: shaders

[image]

i really don't know where i messed up . if someone could  help me.. i am using blender 2.91
[image]

Comment: Have a look at your Image Texture node. The image you selected seems to be the Ambient Occlusion map (..._AO_... in the name) not the normal map (..._NRM_...)

Comment: oh thank you very much, it worked...